# Error 403 when trying to control playback on another device through spotipy library (Spotify Web API)

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

**Describe the bug**

I am getting the 403 error whenever I try to start playback on a Spotify device.

I am attempting playback on my Google Home Mini speaker (using another library called pychromecast but that is working) with this code `client.start_playback(device_id=spotify_device_id, context_uri=tag_uri)` on line 197.

The 403 error is usually when the user does not have Premium (I think). *I have Premium though* and have double-checked. The authorization works fine.

**My code**

https://pastebin.com/fha4Rbdh

**Expected behavior**

- Read Spotify album URI from an NFC tag
- Start playback of that album on a Spotify device (my Google Home Mini)

**Actual behavior**

- Reads Spotify album URI from an NFC tag
- Attempts to start playback on Spotify device
- Fails with 403 error

**Output**

https://pastebin.com/Ejizn084

**Environment:**

- OS: Raspberry Pi 3
- Python version 3.5.3
- spotipy version 2.13.0

**Additional context**

My code worked on Windows 10, then after being transferred to my pi it has no longer worked.
I thought it was not authorizing correctly (it wasn't) so I fixed that, but I am still getting this same error.

I think this error might have something to do with the scope I am using, which is:

```
_scope = 'streaming user-read-playback-state user-modify-playback-state'
```

Please help!

Comment: Just as an aside: `streaming` is a scope only for the Web Playback SDK. Otherwise they seem to be fine. Spotify returns reasons for errors when playback actions are restricted. Can you examine the response to find out if it had one? [Here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/object-model/#player-error-reasons) is an index of the reasons.

Comment: Thanks, Felix! I'll check it out. I think the spotipy library didn't return a reason, just 403. I'll try to make the request with the library and see if I can get the reason.

Comment: You might be able to catch the error and get the raw response that way, I think Spotipy wraps Requests. Try `catch Exception as err` and print `err.response.json()` if I remember right. Sorry, I don't quite have the time to check it all.

Comment: I got an error:
`AttributeError: 'SpotifyException' object has no attribute 'response'`

Comment: I tried printing `err.msg`, `err.http_status`, and `err.code`. `err.msg` printed nothing, `err.http_status` printed 403, and `err.code` printed -1.

Comment: Uh oh. I did some editing to the spotipy source code and printed the reason: `UNKNOWN`. What do I do from here?

Comment: Nice that you got so far! But "unknown" doesn't do much, does it. If you still manage to do it with a desktop, I'd conclude it has something to do with the R-Pi. But I can't imagine what. Or maybe the Google Home device is restricted in some way. You could try comparing it to your desktop app, from both environments. Hard to say.. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem a while ago now, but if I remember correctly, I had been setting the Spotify URIs to lowercase, but Spotify URIs are case-sensitive. So when I made requests to start playback of those URIs, Spotify didn't understand some of them but understood others (URIs that had no uppercase letters). That explains why it worked on my laptop, but not on the raspberry pi. I had used different URIs on each (not very scientific).

It took me 3 months of on and off debugging to solve that one. Sometimes it is the smallest change that fixes the biggest problem.

Comment: You can see the line for yourself [here](https://pastebin.com/fha4Rbdh) on line 179. I have cleaned up the code a lot since then, but this shows the code as it was with the bug-causing line.